# How to Create list view with following records to filter on specific object?

Tags: list-view

We have a requirement to create a new list view to display only what are the records user following on Accounts object?

Comment: What is meant by "the records user following"? Do you mean only records owned by the logged in User?

Comment: If I'm a logged in user to Salesforce In accounts object I'm following 10 records but record owners are different. How Can I create a filter to view all 10 records which I'm following?

Answer (score 0):

In Classic view, you can toggle between List view and Feed view for followed records. See on right hand side of image.

[image]

In Lightning, this is a limitation and has an [open idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E8U8QAK). I suggest voting.